# Pandas: create a new column in a dataframe that is a function of a rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have a data frame and can compute a new column of rolling 10 period means
using `pandas.stats.moments.rolling_mean(ExistingColumn, 10,
min_periods=10)`. If there are fewer than 10 periods available, I get a NaN. I
can do the same for rolling medians. Perfect.

I'd now like to compute other rolling functions of N periods, but can't for the
life of me figure out how to do use a user defined function with Pandas. In
particular, I want to compute a rolling 10 point Hodges Lehman Mean, which is
defined as follows:

```
def hodgesLehmanMean(x): 
    return 0.5 * statistics.median(x[i] + x[j] for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(i+1,len(x)))
```

How can i turn this into a rolling function that can be applied to a Pandas
dataframe and returns a NaN if fewer than 10 periods are passed to it? I'm a
Pandas newbie, so I'd be particularly appreciative of a simple explanation with
an example.

Comment: If you look in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments), you can see the `rolling_apply` function, which allows you to apply any function in a rolling way.  Your function must take the data inside the "rolling window" as an argument.  It's not clear how your hodgesLehmannMean involves a window.  What is `x`?  Is it the window or the whole data set?

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`pandas.rolling_apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments):

```
import numpy as np
def hodgesLehmanMean(x): 
    return 0.5 * np.median([x[i] + x[j] 
                           for i in range(len(x)) 
                           for j in range(i+1,len(x))])

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': np.arange(20, dtype='float')})
df['bar'] = pd.rolling_apply(df['foo'], 10, hodgesLehmanMean)
print(df)
```

yields

```
    foo   bar
0     0   NaN
1     1   NaN
2     2   NaN
3     3   NaN
4     4   NaN
5     5   NaN
6     6   NaN
7     7   NaN
8     8   NaN
9     9   4.5
10   10   5.5
11   11   6.5
12   12   7.5
13   13   8.5
14   14   9.5
15   15  10.5
16   16  11.5
17   17  12.5
18   18  13.5
19   19  14.5
```

A faster version of `hodgesLehmanMean` would be:

```
def hodgesLehmanMean_alt(x): 
    m = np.add.outer(x,x)
    ind = np.tril_indices(len(x), -1)
    return 0.5 * np.median(m[ind])
```

---

Here is a sanity-check showing `hodgesLehmanMean_alt` returns the same value as `hodgesLehmanMean` for 1000 random arrays of length 100:

```
In [68]: m = np.random.random((1000, 100))

In [69]: all(hodgesLehmanMean(x) == hodgesLehmanMean_alt(x) for x in m)
Out[69]: True
```

Here is a benchmark showing `hodgesLehmanMean_alt` is about 8x faster:

```
In [80]: x = np.random.random(5000)

In [81]: %timeit hodgesLehmanMean(x)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.99 s per loop

In [82]: %timeit hodgesLehmanMean_alt(x)
1 loops, best of 3: 463 ms per loop
```

Comment: x is an iterable (typically a list). Your explanation and your example are crystal clear. Thanks a mill.

Comment: Apologies for not responding earlier, but your code is remarkable in that it speeds up the routine by an order of magnitude. Thank you for this. It's worth pointing out that the Hodges Lehman mean is a very useful estimator because of its very high (95%) efficiency in the standard (Gaussian) case, along with the ability to reject arbitrarily large outliers so long as they do not exceed 29% of the points. In short, it gives us most of the efficiency of the mean, with much of the robustness and none of the shortcomings (e.g. locking in to a static central value) of the median. Thanks again.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date with recent version of pandas - any plan in updating it?