# Pandas: using rolling windows with user functions

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe from which I estimate 10 year rolling averages of various kinds with the old style rolling syntax:

```
`pandas.rolling_mean(df['x'], 10)`, 
`pandas.rolling_median(df['x'], 10)`
```

and

```
`pandas.rolling_apply(df['x'],10, hodgesLehmanMean)`,
```

where hodgesLehman mean is a function i wrote (see below).

```
def hodgesLehmanMean(x):
    #Computes the Hodges-Lehman mean = median { [x_i + x+j]/2 }. 
    #Robust to 29% outliers, with high (95% efficiency) in the gaussian case

    N = len(x)
    return 0.5 * numpy.median(x[i] + x[j] for i in range(N) for j in range(i+1,N))
`
```

Now that the old rolling functions have been deprecated, i am trying to rewrite my code in the new style series.rolling() style, i.e.:

```
`df['x'].rolling(window=10).mean()`, 
`df['x'].rolling(window=10).median()`
 and 
`df['x'].rolling(window=10).hodgesLehmanMean()`.
```

The first two (mean and median) work like a charm. The third (hodgesLehmanMean) does not work - it raises an `AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'hodgesLehmanMean`

How can i get my function to work with the new series.rolling syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `Rolling.apply`/`agg`:

```
df['x'].rolling(window=10).agg(hodgesLehmanMean)
```

---

Also, note that in your function, you want to pass a *list* to `np.median`, not a *generator*:

```
def hodgesLehmanMean(x): 
    return 0.5 * np.median([x[i] + x[j] 
                           for i in range(len(x)) 
                           for j in range(i+1,len(x))])
```

For faster implementations of `hodgesLehmanMean`, look at [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990702/4909087) to one of your older questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27990497/4909087).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer - worked like a charm. I was unaware of agg, and got it working right away using your guidance. I actually use unutbu's faster implementation of hodgesLehmanMean that was posted in response to an earlier question of mine, but deliberately did not post it, in case it caused any confusion about the nature of my problem. Thanks again!  Thomas Philips

Comment: Indeed it did, and I have accepted the answer and voted on it as well. Thanks again.